# How to make a search function to search through a table from a my sql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search

I have a page at the minute which is displaying all the records within my 'student' table in my mysql database, I need a function which allows a user to pick any of the variable in the table and a  search box to appear to allow a user to search by the corresponding variable.

E.g a drop down box holding all the variables within the student table and on choosing a variable a text box appears to allow the user to enter some text and it will search through the table.

At the minute my code is simply displaying all records within the student table I have no idea where to start with the search function I have tried numerous examples but each time I break the code I have.

ANY help would be MUCH appreciated :)

```
<?php
$dbQuery = $db->prepare("select * from student order by Forename asc");
$dbQuery->execute();

$numStudent = $dbQuery->rowCount();

echo "<p>There are $numStudent students in the system</p>";
if (isset($lastInserted)) {
    echo "<p>The last student added has ID=$lastInserted</p>";
}

$oddRow=true;
while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ID       = $dbRow['ID'];
    $Forename = $dbRow['Forename'];
    $Surname  = $dbRow['Surname'];
    $Email  = $dbRow['Email'];
    $B_number = $dbRow['B_number'];
    $School = $dbRow['School'];
    $Campus = $dbRow['Campus'];
    $Research_Institute = $dbRow['Research_Institute'];
    $FTPT = $dbRow['FTPT'];

    if ($oddRow) $rowClass="odd"; else $rowClass="even";
    $oddRow=!$oddRow;

        echo "<tr class='$rowClass'><td>$Forename</td><td>$Surname</td><td>$Email</td><td>$B_number</td><td>$School</td><td>$Campus</td><td>$Research_Institute</td><td>$FTPT</td>
                  <td class='operation'>
              </tr>";

}


?>
</table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very general question, and too much code pasted in window above... I'm sure you're looking for some JavaScript / AJAX solution, but you need at least to start building it.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to update your query to say something like this. You need `where` if you want to filter only certain rows from your table.

```
select * 
  from student 
 where Forename = 'searchterm'
    or Surname = 'searchterm'
    or School = 'searchterm'
     order by Forename asc
```